# Is there a way to find the former value of a field changed after the standard 'edit' method within MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

First some code of what I'm trying to do:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Edit(Person person, HttpPostedFileBase filetoupload)
{
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
            //db is the context and person is the object to be changed
            person.PeopleManagerApproved = false;
            Person x = db.Persons.Find(person.ID);
            //connection with the database to persist the changes.
            db.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("../Person/Details/" + person.ID);
       }
       return View(person);
 }
```

when I run this code though, the database says that it can't save because there's another entity with the same primary key. This is logical as I'm selecting it from the database as it's being altered. Is there a way however, to grab that object so I can check the previous value of a field declared within the object so I know which values have changed after editting the 'person' object.

the error message is:

```
Attaching an entity of type 'Smoelenboek.Models.Person' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.
```

Comment: Try attaching the entity `db.Entry.Attach(person);` before calling `EntityState.Modified`. Alternatively just update the properties of `x` based on `person` and Save. Note also it should be `return RedirectToAction("Details", new {id = person.ID});`

Comment: What is the purpose of `x`? You are populating it from the DB then never using it.

Comment: because that's where the error occurse but i've solved it now with this code: List<Person> checkiffalseapproved = db.Persons.AsNoTracking().Where(y => y.ID == person.ID).AsQueryable().ToList(); this way it's detached from the original database and i can still obtain the information without bothering the EF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List checkiffalseapproved = db.Persons.AsNoTracking().Where(y => y.ID == person.ID).AsQueryable().ToList(); this way it's detached from the original database and i can still obtain the information without bothering the EF

this code fixed it